# How to protect the routes in react route version of 6.22.3 with react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

This is app component using react and react router vesrion of 6.22.3 app.tsx

```
   {
     path: "/",
     element: <LayoutTemplate></LayoutTemplate>,
     children: [
       {
         index: true, element: <DashBoard />,
       },
       {
         path: "/dashboard", element: <DashBoard />,
       },
     ]
   },
   {
     path: "/login", element: <Login />,
   },
   {
     path: "*",
     element: <Newfound />
   }
```

This is auth provider from AUTH context

```
 \<AuthProvider\>
 \<RouterProvider router={router} /\>
 \</AuthProvider\>
```

This is a Protected  component

```
This is a Protected  component all routes after all the routes coming after Localhost/
 How to apply Protected components to above configured routes after the root path '/'
 const Protected: React.FC<ProtectedProps\> = () => {
 const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
 if (!isAuthenticated) {
 return \<Navigate to "/login"/\>
 }
 return \<Outlet \>\</Outlet\>
 };
 export default Protected;
```

BY using Protected component how to protect the routes? for above configured routes